# R markdown: Error in FUN(X[[i]], …): cannot coerce type 'symbol' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Even though I can run my code without a problem, when I was trying to knit the markdown file into HTML, these two simple lines of code give me this error:

> R markdown: Error in FUN(X[[i]], …): cannot coerce type 'symbol' to vector of type 'double' Calls:  ... WithVisible -> eval -> eval -> data.frame -> apply Execution halted

```
sapply(data, levels)
numdata <- data.frame(lapply(data, as.numeric))
```

Does anyone know why it happens and how to solve it? I would be very grateful for your help

Comment: I can replicate this problem by starting a fresh R session and running `lapply(data, as.numeric)` because `data` is a built-in function. Your error message suggests that you do not have an object called `data` being created in your Rmd script prior to this line being called. My guess is that it works in your console because you have an object called `data` in your Global environment that you have previously created.

Comment: As @Allan is saying, the `data` object is problematic. If you want to stitch an R markdown file, you should imagine that the markdown document is a standalone self-referential code environment. For example, I would never run an analysis in the console, create a few object that I want to visualize, then put a series of `print()` statements around them in the code blocks of an Rmd. Build the entire analysis into the Rmd, even if you're running a `source("../myanalysis.R")` in the top code block. And don't use labels like `data` or `true` or `if` or `for` for data objects.

Comment: The data I used was from a Rdata file. Is there a way to solve the problem? Do I have to convert Rdata to csv files first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Allan and @quickreaction. The data was given in a Rdata file. So when I opened it, it loads into my Global Environment. It doesn't satisfy the condition that "markdown document is a standalone self-referential code environment"

I solved it by including

```
write.csv(data,'data.csv')
data<-read.csv('data.csv')
```